# Add global plugin for Mongoose on runtime

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently trying to attach a global Mongoose on runtime with no luck. My plugin requires a few dependencies and options generated upon my app's bootstrapping thus I need to add it sequentially. Mongoose seems to ignore everything wrapped within a closure.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const config = {};
const {DB_CONNECT} = process.env;

const myPlugin = schema => {
  console.log('done'); // this line is not logged at all
  schema.methods.mymethod = () => {};
}

const connectAndAddPlugins = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(
    DB_CONNECT,
    {...config}
  );
  mongoose.plugin(myPlugin)
};

connectAndAddPlugins();
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is at least one mistake in your code. `await` function can only be inside `async`. So `connectAndAddPlugins ` should be `async`, not `await`

Comment: @rkm I put together a simple snippet to showcase the problem. I have updated the sample and it actually works as expected still without updating the global mongoose plugins

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, since a model gets compiled and loaded with Mongoose global plugins are not attached anymore thus models should get registered afterwards:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const config = {};
const {DB_CONNECT} = process.env;

const myPlugin = schema => {
  console.log('done'); // this line is not logged at all
  schema.methods.mymethod = () => {};
}

const connectAndAddPlugins = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(
    DB_CONNECT,
    {...config}
  );
  mongoose.plugin(myPlugin)
};

const loadModels = () => {
  const model = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });
}

connectAndAddPlugins();
loadModels();
```